# Removing substring (suffix) from Bash variable with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a tenuous grasp of Bash scripting and piping, and have encountered a situation where my limited-experience-based expectation conflicts with reality. I want to remove a substring (specifically a suffix) from a Bash variable using sed. The string and substring are both Bash variables.

```
> foo1=foo.cpp
> foo2=/main/bar/foo.cpp
> foo3=$(echo $foo2 | sed 's/$foo1//')
> echo $foo3
/main/bar/foo.cpp
```

If I use a hardcoded string in the sed expression in place of $foo1, the expression behaves as desired:

```
> foo4=$(echo $foo2 | sed 's/foo\.cpp//')
> echo $foo4
/main/bar/
```

Can anyone point out what I'm missing to make the foo3 evaluation work such that "foo.cpp" is deleted? Thank you.

Comment: I have tried double-quoting foo1, foo2, and both in the foo3 expression; it does not change the resulting value of foo3.

Comment: Screw sed: `echo ${foo2%%$foo1}`

Comment: Thank you @sat. I'll add this to my bag of tricks for Bash string manipulations.

Comment: Thank you @bishop. Screwing sed is also a workable solution for me. :) Owing to my tenuous grasp of unix-shell string manipulations, I'm often unclear when strings need to be piped to secondary programs versus when they can be "natively" manipulated by the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU bash 4 and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32):

```
foo1="foo.cpp"
foo2="/main/bar/foo.cpp"
foo3="${foo2%$foo1}"
echo "$foo3"
```

Output:

```
/main/bar/
```